# Finding the fastest possible path

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, physics

I have an object with width w and height h. The object needs to find the fastest possible path to cover the entire area in the least amount of time. Think of it like a robotic arm that needs to spray a chemical onto the entire surface. The black regions are areas that cannot be transversed.

[image: Object moving through an area]

In the image above, the w by h object is moving across an area (the dark gray region behind it is area that has already been covered). I need to work out an algorithm that determines the fastest possible path to cover the entire area if the object moves at a speed v and takes t seconds to make a 90 degree turn (or t/90 for each 1 degree turn). The object can move outside the designated area.

The goal should be to minimize the number of turns and maximize linear movement. Assuming I have all of the measurements for everything, how would I start programming something that can determine this path?

Comment: It seems like the scope of this problem is too large for SO.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Does it have to turn to move sideways?  Eg, from position shown can it move parallel to y axis and sweep out a path that's `w` wide, with no cost for a turn?  If not, why specify `w`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[edited answer]**
I'm sorry I was wrong.

To me the best solution would be an algorithm that looks like this:

```
1. what is the smallest rectangle that covers the all area
2. compute the time to 'paint it' from your starting position:
    2.1 as you can go outside, just
        2.1.1 calculate time  if browsing by rows
        2.1.2 if by column
        2.1.3 if turning from outer to center
        2.1.4 if turning from outer to center
    2.2 decide what is the most efficient solution
3. store this result
4. subdivise the area in 2 smaller rectangles
5. redo the same thing for the 2 and test various combination for the travel from rectangle 1 to 2 (obviously the starting pos on 2 is free) Always keep track that anything bigger than the cost of the first solution can be ignored
```

If I could give a simple guess, that is not mathematically the fastest, but a good solution
is what most AOI do, just do the biggest rectangle.

The problem mathematically depends on a lot of variables, if t is important (often true for robots) then the simple solution is probably close to the solution aas that s the solution with the minimum turn.

Already finding the best solution for a rectangle is good.
then is is a question of graph (a graph of rectangles, the connexions between the graphs are another problem)

sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Thank you! I would be super indebted to you if you could write up an example.